# Seaborn pairplot is closing immediately

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a pairplot using seaborn. This is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("datasets/iris.csv", index_col=0).drop("species", axis=1);

print(df.head())
res = sns.pairplot(data=df, kind="scatter")
pyplot.show()
```

But it is shown for few milliseconds and then it closes. How to fix this?

Comment: Do `res.figure.show()` instead.

Comment: @Guimoute Doesn't help, any more ideas?

Comment: `.show(block=True)`